# Is there an hgignore.io?

Tags: mercurial, hgignore

I use git for school, but mercurial for work.

Is there an equivalent of [gitignore.io](https://www.gitignore.io/) for mercurial?

Comment: They should be intercompatible.

Comment: What about the `syntax: glob`, is that necessary?

Comment: yes-ish... .hgignore knows both glob and regex. Not sure what is default interpretation (glob I believe)

Comment: @planetmaker: as described in `hg help ignore`, the default is regular expressions. (Regex is also considerably faster, or was when we were using hg heavily, though it's not obvious why this should be the case.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Though there does not seem to be an hgignore.io, you *can* **use any ignore file** generated by [gitignore.io](http://gitignore.io) by simply **placing `syntax: glob`** on the first line.

.hgignore

```
syntax: glob

# Created by https://www.gitignore.io/api/java,eclipse,netbeans,intellij

### Eclipse ###

.metadata
bin/
tmp/
*.tmp
...
```

More info [about `.hgignore`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/.hgignore) files.

Comment: A warning here, Mercurial isn't compatible with the exceptions of gitignore, so lines starting with a `!` are processed as files with names starting with an exclamation mark instead of exceptions. You would need to add those files manually in a commit, once they are committed the will stay tracked.